# log4j2: log to rolling file and stdout using properties

Tags: log4j2

I'm tying to create a logger that logs to a rolling file and my console at the same time. Each by itself works perfectly fine, but in combination only the rolling works. Maybe I'm doing something wrong and did not propertly understand log4j2.

I hope someone can help me.

My properties file is the following:

```
status = error

name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter

filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console, rolling

appender.console.type = Console

appender.console.name = STDOUT

appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout

appender.console.layout.pattern = %-4r %-5p [%t] %c - %m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile

appender.rolling.name = RollingFile

appender.rolling.fileName = mypathtofilehere

appender.rolling.filePattern = CrashDesigner-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz

appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout

appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy

appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

appender.rolling.strategy.max = 40

loggers = rolling.file

logger.rolling.file.name = com.myapp

logger.rolling.file.level = debug

logger.rolling.file.additivity = false

logger.rolling.file.appenderRefs = rolling

logger.rolling.file.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

rootLogger.level = debug

rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout

rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities here. Either

1. Change following line to true: `logger.rolling.file.additivity = true`

   or
2. Add second AppenderRef `logger.rolling.file.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT`

Also you should remove lines with `.appenderRefs`. There is no such appenderRef**s** entity in log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

Each logger can write to more than one appender. For that it should have reference to all those appenders, which can be achieved using appenderRefs.

```
logger.rolling.file.appenderRefs = rolling, stdout

logger.rolling.file.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

logger.rolling.file.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

This will make every logevent triggered by logger 'rolling.file', to be appended to appenders STDOUT and RollingFle.